# Access violation when trying to convert string to enum type

Tags: delphi, enums

I'm trying to convert a string into an enum type. The enum type itself is located in another unit (not the main form, but in the uses of the main form).

```
Type
  TLetter = 'A'..'Z';
```

On the main form, I'm calling a function which takes 2 TLetter as parameters, and I get them from 2 edit boxes on the main form. I convert them like this:

```
var
  L1, L2: TLetter;
begin
  L1 := TLetter(GetEnumValue(TypeInfo(TLetter), EditBox1.Text));
  L2 := TLetter(GetEnumValue(TypeInfo(TLetter), EditBox2.Text));
end;
```

But I get this exception: class $C0000005 'access violation at 0x00436f82: read of address 0xb62c0002'.

Comment: Is here a question? `GetEnumValue` can return -1 if the input is invalid. Please provide a minimal example that reproduces your problem.

Comment: @LURD The problem is reproduced as long as the Type declaration is in another unit, with the current example.

Comment: I also tried `L1:=TLetter(GetEnumValue(TypeInfo(TLetter), 'A'));` but I get the same error.

Comment: TLetter is an ordinal type and not an enum type. You can't do that.

Comment: The ´TLetter´ isn't enum but subrange type so you can't use GetEnumValue

Comment: Oh I see my mistake. Thank you. So my other option would be this `TLetter = (A,B,C and so on)` ?

Comment: @Gab Why do you need an enumerated type or a subrange? What are you trying to achieve? Why not use string or char?

Comment: @Gab No, that would not be the proper way to do this. Enum types are not intended to be used like that. But if you really have to, then do something like `TLetter = (ltA,ltB,ltC...)` instead

Comment: @JerryDodge your code is the same as gab's

Comment: @David Somewhat, my point was that if OP absolutely needs to use enums, then it should be a bit more than just `A,B,C...` as a recommendation, obviously not as any answer

Comment: @JerryDodge Scoped enums could be used. But enums just suck here. Really bad idea.

Comment: @David Indeed they aren't, and I don't think OP intends to use them anyway - it was just the use of the wrong terminology in the first place. But if enums are used, they should at least have a common prefix on each.

Comment: @JerryDodge Or be scoped enums which are better

Comment: Also, you've confused string type and character type. `TypeOf('A') = Char`